# Adding a Settings.bundle to iPhone app

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I am trying to add Settings.bundle to my FIRST iphone app but after adding the bundle file i found out I can't expand the settings file and edit the Roots.plist file according to the instructions. I noticed though that after building the app I can see the application settings in my iPhone settings with some default entries. I'll like to say I am using iOS 5 SDK and xcode 4.2 and am wondering whether that is the cause of the problem and if so how do I go about editing it. I have tried removing the extension to see if it will open as a normal folder but was not successful.

Thanks,

Comment: I think it is a problem (maybe not a problem but the way it was designed). I installed xCode 4.1 and was able to expand the Settings.bundle file but anytime I open on xCode 4.2 can't. I mainly just used the 4.1 to edit the bundle and continue development on the 4.2 version. It will be nice to know how to edit the Setting.bundle file in xCode 4.2 though. This issue is close for me but will leave it open in case someone might have a better idea and save someone some invaluable time. Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Had the same problem after installing XCode 4.2. I've found a simple fix:

```
1) Click on the Settings.Bundle file, go over to the utilities window,
and look in the File Inspector.
2) Using the drop-down, change the file type to 'Application Bundle'
```

Good luck!

Comment: so I have this same problem but I can't change the type... the File Type drop-down does not appear for the bundle. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply! It seems like a bug in xcode 4.2, but oh well. Works now anyway :)